# Select a particular value from a JSON array

Tags: json, scala

I have a JSON array containing the following details, I would like to extract the text Alignment value of Right and assign it to a val.

```js
"data":[
  {
    "formatType": "text",
    "value": "bgyufcie huis huids hufhsduhfsl hd"
  },
  {
    "formatType": "text size",
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "formatType": "text alignment",
    "value" : "right"
  }
]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon) FTW!

Here is a test that demonstrates how easily the "right" value can be found in samples like yours:

```
import com.github.pathikrit.dijon._

val json = parse(
  """{
    |"data":[
    |  {
    |    "formatType": "text",
    |    "value": "bgyufcie huis huids hufhsduhfsl hd"
    |  },
    |  {
    |    "formatType": "text size",
    |    "value": 12
    |  },
    |  {
    |    "formatType": "text alignment",
    |    "value" : "right"
    |  }
    |]
    |}""".stripMargin)

assert(json.data.toSeq.collect { 
  case obj if obj.formatType == "text alignment" => obj.value 
}.head == "right")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library, you can map the json in a Java object.

So, you have to create a class like this:

```
public class MyObject{
    private String formatType;
    private String value;

    //Constuctors, Getter and Setter...
    //.....
    //.....
}
```

After, using the method `fromJson` you can create an array of `MyObject`.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject[] array = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("file.json"), MyObject[].class);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use json4s library as shown next:

```scala
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val json = """{
     "data":[
            {
                "formatType": "text",
                "value": "bgyufcie huis huids hufhsduhfsl hd"
            },
            {
                "formatType": "text size",
                "value": 12
            },
            {
                "formatType": "text alignment",
                "value" : "right"
             }
             ]
}"""

val parsed = parse(json)

val value = (parsed \ "data" \\ classOf[JObject]).filter(m => m("formatType") == "text alignment")(0)("value")

// value: Any = right
```

The filter `(parsed \ "data" \\ classOf[JObject])` extracts all the items into a List of Map i.e:

```
List(
   Map(formatType -> text, value -> bgyufcie huis huids hufhsduhfsl hd), 
   Map(formatType -> text size, value -> 12), Map(formatType -> text alignment, value -> right)
).
```

From those we apply the filter `filter(m => m("formatType") == "text alignment")` to retrieve the record that we really need.

Comment: I tried this, but am getting an error saying
val parsed = parse (json)
required json input , found JSArray

Comment: `parse(....)` accepts a string json are sure you are passing a string in the function? The error says that `json` is not a string. Also make sure that the json is enclosed with brackets as shown above

Comment: @ShanMarshBubashan are you looking for a java or scala solution?

Comment: am searching for a scala solution, And I am passing a Option[JsArray] inside parse

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/jackson/src/main/scala/org/json4s/jackson/JsonMethods.scala) you can find the definition of `parse()`. You must pass a string and not `Option[JsArray]`! BTW why Option[JsArray]? How did you come up with Option[JsArray]?

Comment: ok now I see you missed to mention an important information here, that you use Play framework and therefore you have JSON data inside a JsArray object which is part of `play.api.libs.json` library. Is that correct? The above solution assumes that the input is a string and works only if the input is a string

Comment: I got the parse thing working using the below 

`val data_json = report.data.toString
val parsed = parse(data_json)`

I passed JsArray from another object called report, which receives a Option[JsArray] input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205544/discussion-between-alexandros-biratsis-and-shan-marsh-bubashan).

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Jackson library, it is very helpful for parsing JSON. You can read the JSON using an ObjectMapper.

Here is a full tutorial to get you started: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-parse-json/

Answer (score 0):

create a multiline JSON string, then parse that string directly into a Scala object, use the net.liftweb package to solve this.

```
import net.liftweb.json._

object SarahEmailPluginConfigTest {

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
case class Mailserver(url: String, username: String, password: String)

val json = parse(
"""
{ 
  "url": "imap.yahoo.com",
  "username": "myusername",
  "password": "mypassword"
}
"""
)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val m = json.extract[Mailserver]
    println(m.url)
    println(m.username)
    println(m.password)
  }

}
```

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-scala-lift-json-example-lift-framework

Reference link